# Tool that will automate my build (JavaScript Application)

Tags: javascript, windows, build

I am currently working on Windows, and developing in Netbeans IDE. My project is a git repo, I do commits and push to a server for backup.

Now when I am done with a version, I want to have an automated system that will spit out a zipfile based on my instructions.

What does it need to do:

- Minify all the JS and CSS files it finds in my source folder
- Increment the version number in a Manifest.json file
- Zip the source directory and store the file somewhere

Pretty basic stuff I think. I am free to all suggestions, whether its doing it with a batch script, netbeans, git, or maybe a whole other route all together.

Comment: I would suggest grunt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://gruntjs.com/ is a good automation tool.

From their web page:

> you can use Grunt to automate just 
>   about anything with a minimum of effort

- Minify all the JS and CSS files it finds in my source folder
  https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-uglify
  https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-mincss
- Increment the version number in a Manifest.json file
  https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-version
- Zip the source directory and store the file somewhere
  https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-compress

Download and install nodejs from http://nodejs.org/ and install grunt and the packages:
    `cd /your/project`
    `npm install grunt grunt-cli grunt-contrib-compress grunt-contrib-mincss grunt-contrib-uglify grunt-version`

and I would also use https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-clean if you want to remove the minified files after you have zipped them.